# Android - Custom Keyboard on manually inflated listview row not showing

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, keyboard

Good day.

I have an android application. In my application, I have a custom listView with 5 columns that are textViews. The user can click the rows, once he does, the row layout will change, changing the last 2 textViews to EditTexts. I then register the new EditTexts onto my custom keyboard [taken from this example](http://www.fampennings.nl/maarten/android/09keyboard/index.htm) - kindly note that I did a functional copy-paste of his example with regards to the custom keyboard class and how to make it work in the main layout. However, when I click the EditText in the row, my custom keyboard does not show up at all.

I have a global variable as such:

```
CustomKeyboard mCustomKeyboard;
```

And in my `onCreate()` method in the activity, I do:

```
mCustomKeyboard= new CustomKeyboard(this, R.id.keyboardview, R.xml.custom_keyboard);
```

This is my layout, I have the KeyboardView at the bottom of the Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".SearchResult" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <!-- A lot of views go here, enclosed in my linear layout -->

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView
        android:id="@+id/keyboardview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the code that changes the layout. What I do is that I take the row values from the old layout, get the new layout `search_result_inflate`, then set the texts of the new layout using the values I got. Kindly note the `mCustomKeyboard.registerEditText(R.id.qtyInputSearchResult);` line after inflating the layout:

```
private void changeLayout(final View view){

    //get views from old layout
    TextView textViewQuantity = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.qtyInput);
    TextView textViewDiscountReq = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.discInput);
    TextView textViewName = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.dialogItemName);
    TextView textViewPrice = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.price);
    TextView textViewDiscount = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.discount);

    //store values in strings
    String itemName = textViewName.getText().toString();
    String itemPrice = textViewPrice.getText().toString();
    String itemDiscount = textViewDiscount.getText().toString();
    String itemQty = textViewQuantity.getText().toString();
    String itemDisc = textViewDiscountReq.getText().toString();

    //set the view to gone
    textViewQuantity.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    textViewDiscountReq.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    textViewName.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    textViewPrice.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    textViewDiscount.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    //get the old layout
    LinearLayout ll_inflate = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.search_result_layout);

    //get the inflate/new view
    View child = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.search_result_inflate, null);

    //get the views in the new view, populate them
    TextView newName = (TextView)child.findViewById(R.id.dialogItemName);
    newName.setText(itemName);

    TextView newDiscount = (TextView)child.findViewById(R.id.discount);
    newDiscount.setText(itemDiscount);

    TextView newPrice = (TextView)child.findViewById(R.id.price);
    newPrice.setText(itemPrice);

    EditText qtyInput = (EditText)child.findViewById(R.id.qtyInputSearchResult);
    qtyInput.setText(itemQty);

    EditText discInput = (EditText)child.findViewById(R.id.discInputSearchResult);
    discInput.setText(itemDisc);

    //show new layout
    ll_inflate.removeAllViews();
    ll_inflate.removeAllViewsInLayout();
    ll_inflate.addView(child);

    mCustomKeyboard.registerEditText(R.id.qtyInputSearchResult); 
}
```

Here is my `search_result_inflate.xml file`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/search_result_inflate"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:minHeight="50dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="1dip"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="1dip" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dialogItemName"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.54"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Item Name"
            android:textSize="23sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/price"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.14"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Price"
            android:textSize="23sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/discount"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.10"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Discount"
            android:textSize="23sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/qtyInputSearchResult"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.14"
            android:background="@layout/edittext_selector"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="qtyInput"
            android:textColorHighlight="@color/white_opaque"
            android:textSize="23sp" >
        </EditText>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/discInputSearchResult"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.11"
            android:background="@layout/edittext_selector"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="discInput"
            android:textColorHighlight="@color/white_opaque"
            android:textSize="23sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

As you can see, I have 2 editTexts and I registered `qtyInputSearchResult` to the custom keyboard class. However, the custom keyboard does not show up.

I also tried to use the custom keyboard class on an editText in another activity and it works just fine. Am I missing something here? I'm confused as to why the custom keyboard does not show up properly.

Any help is very much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it, I placed the keyboard layout in the search_result_inflate.xml like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/search_result_inflate"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:minHeight="50dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="1dip"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="1dip" >

        <!-- a lot of components here -->

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView
        android:id="@+id/keyboardview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</RelativeLayout>
```